# How to check if a webpage is hanging (keep loading)?

Tags: java, timeout, connection, maximo

I'm trying to write a java class to check if the webpage interface of my Maximo application is fully loaded or hanging. If it's hanging then a restart script will be run to restart the application.

I can check the application up or down (using Maximo connect()) but don't know how to do the same for the webpage interface because sometimes I can connect() to the application but the webpage is not responding, it's just keep loading on the browser.

Basically, I need a way to try loading the application URL, if after 5 minutes, it's still loading then restart the server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question:

> Basically, I need a way to try loading the application URL, if after 5 minutes, it's still loading then restart the server.

Unless you have a side channel of some sort the only way to tell is a timeout.

Comment: silly me, forgot about the URL, Connection.connect() stuffs. I'm testing it out to see if it can solve my case. Thanks anyway :)